# SVN server line with password w/ svn+ssh transport

Tags: svn

I can connect to svn having login in my server address like this

```
svn+ssh://login@someIp/somepath
```

Is it possible also have password there?

Comment: Which platform? Which client? I'm currently answering for the official Subversion client on unixlike operating systems (MacOS X, Linux); it would help if we knew your actual target environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. Subversion's delegation to an external SSH process has no support for passing passwords. As part of the point of using SSH is to avoid interception of plaintext passwords, this would (by caching those passwords) be a serious bug if it were supported, and the lack of this "feature" is by-design.

What you can do is use RSA key authentication to allow single-sign-on (ideally, encrypting your key, such that your operating system prompts for that key's password the first time you try to use it, then remembers it thereafter; MacOS X and modern GNOME -- so stock Ubuntu -- will do this out-of-the-box).

Use the `ssh-keygen` command to generate an RSA key pair, and cause the public half of it to be installed in the `authorized_keys` file for your user on the SVN server. (Some sites may also allow RSA public keys to be installed in LDAP; your system administrator will be able to tell you more).

Incidentally, it's not even necessary to have your username in the URL either. You can apply appropriate configuration in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host your-svn-server
  User your-login-name
  IdentityFile /path/to/your/key # the private half of your keypair
```

If you use the default filename for your key, it will not be necessary to configure its location; this is only really necessary if you use more than one key per workstation.